# MarkLogic - How to get a list of field indexes

Tags: marklogic

How can I declare namespace and navigate to element node field-name.  I have 40 field indexes just want to get a list of field-name only.    Thanks.

```
<field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database">

<field-name>externalIDField</field-name>
<field-path>
   <path>//agreement:externalID</path>
   <weight>1</weight>
</field-path>
<field-value-searches>true</field-value-searches>
<included-elements>
</included-elements>
<excluded-elements>
</excluded-elements>
<tokenizer-overrides>
</tokenizer-overrides>
</field>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the admin API. Specifically:

```
import module namespace admin="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
       at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
 declare namespace db="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database";

admin:database-get-fields(
  admin:get-configuration(), xdmp:database("myDatabase"))//db:field-name/data(.)
```